# Why is this recursive TypeScript function returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion

I'm trying to recursively traverse a tree of objects that contain objects that contain objects, build a string, and return the string as part of a VSCode extension.

```
type categories = { [key: string]: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } } };

const recurseThroughTree = (categories: categories, outputString: string = '', i: number = 0): string => {
  if (i < 2) {
    const categoryKeys: Array<string> = Object.keys(categories);
    const randomCategoryIndex: number = categoryKeys.indexOf(categoryKeys[Math.floor(categoryKeys.length * Math.random())]);
    const randomCategoryName: string = categoryKeys[randomCategoryIndex];
    const randomCategories: any = categories[randomCategoryName];

    outputString += `${randomCategoryName} > `;

    i = i + 1;

    recurseThroughTree(randomCategories, outputString, i);
  } else {
    outputString += categories.text;
    // This logs the correct output
    console.log(outputString);

    return outputString;
  }
};
```

I would expect this to return the outputString ( which logs correctly ), but it returns undefined.

Answer (score 3):

I think you miss a return when calling your recursive function:

```
i = i + 1;

return recurseThroughTree(randomCategories, outputString, i);
```

Comment: That did it!  Thank you so much!

Can you say why the return statement is needed?

Comment: Because there is a call stack: recurseThroughTree => recurseThroughTree => recurseThroughTree => etc... and if there is no return the result will never returned to its parent and its grand parent, etc..